# FeatureLayer access via arcgis online in html

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

See below for part of html code my `featureLayer` is saved in my `arcgisonline`;

```
var search = new Search({
        sources: [{
          featureLayer: new FeatureLayer("https://services1.arcgis.com/BZNs0xaSHDSi4V6G/arcgis/rest/services/postcodes/FeatureServer/0",
```

When I run the code, it ask to enter arcgisonline username and password.
when I do this, it says incorrect username and password.

This is the same username and password, I would have used to login in directly in my ArcGIS account.

Any hint or suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you might be typing incorrectly.

Because this is the only way to access secured(Non shared) layer. You HAVE to enter the AGOL credentials while accessing the secured (non shared) layer in your application.

There is alternative way to avoid the `identity manager or Credentials` simply share your **AGOL GIS feature layer** with everyone.

As you can see in below screenshot. (these are the layers published by you)

[image]

I am not able to see **"postcodes"** layers in it.

This can also be a reason that either you haven't publish the layer properly or it's not shared with anyone.